# OR in includes in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a problem, i need to return `boolean` when my array include at least one of the object, so in my `if` statement I use `||` operator, but id does not work

my code:

first case:

```
//my array
const array = ['one'];

if(array.includes('one' || 'two' || 'three') {
    return true;
}

//return true
```

second case:

```
const array = ['two'];

if(array.includes('one' || 'two' || 'three') {
    return true;
}

//return false
```

can someone tell me, why in the second case, my `if` statement return me `false` when i provide a one of the correct object?

thanks for any help

Comment: Does not exist you'll have to implement it youself.

Comment: In both of your if-clauses there is missing a closing bracket.

Answer (score 1):

`a || b` means "If `a` is a true value, `a`, otherwise `b`".

`'one'` is a true value, so `'one' || 'two' || 'three'` means `'one'`

Thus `array.includes('one' || 'two' || 'three')` means `array.includes('one')`

---

Use `find` and test against all the possible values if you need to check for a match for one of multiple values.

```js
const array = ['two'];

const searching_for = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const first_match = array.find(entry => searching_for.includes(entry));

console.log(first_match);
```

Comment: Ok, but why i second case return me `false` and how to solve this?

Comment: `array.find(item => ['one', 'two', 'three'].includes(item))`

Comment: @dupadupa — Because the array doesn't include `'one'`! And I told you how to solve it already.

Comment: @Quentin but how to use this in if statement?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to actually check for an **array intersection**: as long as one or more elements in both arrays are present, you want to return true.

This can be done by using `Array.prototype.some`, with the inner predicate using `Array.prototype.includes`:

```js
const array = ['two'];
const badArray = ['foobar'];
const acceptedValues = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

function isIntersecting(a1, a2) {
  return a1.some(x => a2.includes(x));
}

console.log(isIntersecting(array, acceptedValues)); // true
console.log(isIntersecting(badArray, acceptedValues)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the OR operator wasn't intended to be used this way. It returns its first operand if it's truthy, otherwise, it returns its second operand.

So, `'one' || 'two' || 'three'` evaluates to `'one'`, as it is truthy; therefore, only `'one'` is passed to `includes` for check:

```js
console.log('one' || 'two' || 'three')
```

Instead, you could use an array method, `Array#some`, to achieve what you want:

```js
//my array
const array = ['two'];

//list of values to check for
const options = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

console.log(array.some(elem => options.includes(elem))) //true
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `array.includes` can only get only one element
2. `'one' || 'two' || 'three'` is considered as `IF 'one' is false/empty/undefined THEN 'two'` not the way you think.

Here there is a code example how you can achieve what you want:

```js
var toCheck = "one";
var valid = ['one','two', 'three'];

function contains(target, pattern){
    var value = 0;
    pattern.forEach(function(word){
      value = value + target.includes(word);
    });
    return (value === 1)
}

console.log(contains(toCheck, valid));
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can just use:

```
const array = ['1','two','smth']
const test (array) => {
  return array.includes('one') || array.includes('two') || array.includes('three')
}
console.log(test(array))
```

Logical or (`||`) will return `true` if at least one statement is `true`.